# Is there a specification for a standard API for streams?

Tags: javascript, stream

There is a standard specification for Promises: Promises/A+.

Similarly, is there a specification for a standard API for streams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no such standard.

W3C and WHATWG are working on a [Streams API specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/streams-api/), see the latest draft (called "living standard" these days) at https://streams.spec.whatwg.org/.

On the server side, the Node.js builtin API has become pretty much the standard. You can read their docs at https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html.

Comment: You seem to quickly take my word for everything, accepting the first answer being posted after 30secs :-)

Comment: FWIW, W3C hasn't really been doing anything in this space for quite a while.

Comment: To add to that, since I realize W3C and WHATWG are sometimes confused, the WHATWG document Bergi points to is definitely what is seen as the standard for streams by browsers and JavaScript engine implementers. Once it lands in browsers more and more APIs will start to work with it.